# Jquery Ajax problem

Tags: xml, ajax, jquery

I'm having an issue and I'm hoping someone could point me in the right direction. I'm trying to parse an xml file using JQuery's .ajax function this is the code:

This code resides in a test.js file

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'test.xml',
        dataType: 'xml',
        success: testIt
    });
 });

 function testIt(xml) {
   alert("Test");
 }
```

This is just a test I'm running at the moment that after performing the ajax request it should call `testIt`. The problem is it doesn't. As this is a test the html, js and xml files are all in the same directory on my Desktop ie `/Users/Chris/Desktop/Development`.

If I add `complete: testIt` it does go into the function. the test.xml and has been checked and is valid.

I'm currently testing using Safari 5.0.5 but I have also tested it in Firefox which acts the same. It is either a quirk of `$.ajax` or more likely its something I'm doing wrong.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: If the complete function executes, and the success doesn't, I suggest to add an error function to the $.ajax and see what is the error message.

Comment: Which jQuery version are you using? When ajaxing local files, the returned status code will be `0` instead of `200` (there is no webserver to send a status code). jQuery 1.5 for example had a problem with checking for `0`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a go at [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/), or the built-in developer tools in Chrome, and take a closer look at the request and results from your ajax call. If `success` doesn't run, but `complete` does, it is likely that the call comes back with an error status for some reason (likely because of the details subtenante outlined in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6276243/jquery-ajax-problem/6276381#6276381)).

I tried your setup on my machine, and added `error: function() { alert("didn't work..."); }` to the ajax options, and as I suspected the request comes back with an error code.

If you're going to use this online in the end, I suggest you upload the xml file somewhere and try to load it from there, to see if that works. (If you're running a local webserver, "somewhere" might be your own computer, but you must link to it with a "real" url, like localhost:8080/something/test.xml).